# Calculate the total remainder of N when divided by the numbers from a to b. Where n, a ,b are the given numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, optimization, programming

I encountered a problem on the web about competitive programming

Problem statement: Given 3 numbers n , a , b $ (n, a , b \le 10^{12}) $. Find the result of the following equation
$$ \sum_{i=a}^b n \ mod \ i $$

Example : $ n = 15, a = 1, b = 5$, the answer is 15 % 1 + 15 % 2 + ... + 15 % 5 = 4
The naive solution got time limit exceeded because the constrain is large. I will be pleased if anyone comes up with a more optimal solution

Thanks much for help!

Comment: Given "*n*"....  But your formula has no *n* but instead *N*.  Please explain.

Comment: The result of $\sum_{i=a}^b N \text{ mod } i$ is $\sum_{i=a}^b N \text{ mod } i$. Or you can rewrite it as $\sum_{i=0}^b N \text{ mod } i - \sum_{i=0}^{a-1} N \text{ mod } i$. There is no simpler formula. Obviously, if $N$ is divisible by $pq$, then it is also divisible by $p$ and $q$, but unless you want to factorize every single number in the interval from $a$ to $b$, the original formula is the best you can get.

Comment: sorry it's my mistake. I have updated my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple formula in general, but (depending on the sizes of the parameters) there may be a shortcut.  Note that if $ki \le n < (k+1) i$, $n \; \text{mod}\; i = n - k i$.
Thus if $k b \le n < (k+1) a$,
$$ \sum_{i=a}^b n\; \text{mod}\; i = \sum_{i=a}^b (n - k i) = (b+1-a)\left(n-\frac{k(a+b)}2\right)$$
Or if $n/a - n/b$ is not too large, you can break up the interval $[a,b]$ into pieces for
different $k = \lfloor n/i \rfloor$.